# Get the Job Status of UIPrintInteractionController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, airprint

I have a problem: I want to know the status of the print job. I'm printing out a PDF file which is temporarily stored in a cloud drive. I want to delete that file after the print job is done. How can I realize this in swift?
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 // 1
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
    // 2
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
    printController.showsPageRange = false
    printInfo.jobName = "PDF ID: " + pdfObjectID
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    // 3
    //let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "Test")
    let formatter = pdf.viewPrintFormatter()
    formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    printController.printFormatter = formatter

    // show PrintController
    printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Can't you use the completion handler for that purpose?

Comment: Yes I think so but I've no idea how to da that.
Referring to this page [UIKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPrintInteractionController/sharedPrintController) I have to use the method `UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler`. Can you maybe provide me an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself, but according to the documentation,
you can pass a [`UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler) as `completionHandler:` parameter:

> When a print job concludes, you can reset any state set up for printing and do related housekeeping tasks.

A simple example:

```
    printController.presentAnimated(true) { (controller, success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            // Printed successfully
            // Remove file here ...
        } else {
            // Printing failed, report error ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mh this code looks fine but it doesn't work.
I've a added window to confirm that the print is okay but it would be really nice if i can solve this automatically

Answer (score 2):

To complement Martin R's answer, you can add the completion handler by declaring a closure. This will be useful if you would like to present the print controller differently depending on the device:

```
    let printCompletionHandler: UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler = { (controller, success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            // Printed successfully
            // Remove file here ...
        } else {
            // Printing failed, report error ...
        }
    }

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
        printController.presentFromRect(self.printButton.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true, completionHandler: printCompletionHandler)
    } else {
        printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: printCompletionHandler)
    }
```

This way you can use the same completion handler for both calls :)